# Запутывание алгоритма сложения двух переменных a и b

Tags: javascript, соревнование, обфускация

Как усложнить сложение двух переменных **a** и **b** в `JavaScript`, чтобы получился максимально [запутанный](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) алгоритм (в разумных пределах, ну или в неразумных)? Недавно встретил интересный вариант в [интернетах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9713/328896). Может у кого есть что-либо похожее?

Код не мой, но мне понравилось:

```js
const amount = (a, b) => {
    const data = {
        fn: a,
        sn: b,
        g: 'getComPart',
        f: 'f',
        getComPart: {
            f: 'computed'
        },
        n: 'n',
        computed: (a) => {
            let z = data['s' + [data[data.n]]];

            while (z) {a++; z--;}
            return a;
        }
    };
    return data[data[data.g].f](data['f' + data.n]);
};

console.log(amount(3, 5)); // 8
```

Хорошо бы еще `a++` и `z--` развернуть в отдельные алгоритмы..

---

По заявкам трудящихся объявляется [конкурс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/info). Критерий победы - число голосов.

Comment: Автор данного кода [Александр Великий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/304342/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80-%d0%92%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9) Его ответ сочли в итоге как спам, а учетную запись заблокировали Вот топик [обсуждения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9713/28748) на мете  Выводы делайте сами

Comment: Тогда бы уж [tag:соревнование] сделал, только надо критерий победы - скорее всего число голосов.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Нууу...

```js
const amount = (a, b) => {
  let c = [];
  let e = () => alert("(~^_^~) Не могу делить на ноль. У меня лапки!");
  return ["(~^_^~)",a*b,a/b,a%b,a**b,a,b].map(
    (a,b,c) => (a + b) / c == 0 ? a * b : a
  ).filter( (a,b,c) => {
   return (String(a).match(/(\D)\./gi) || [0])[0] ? a/b : a
  }).reduce( (a,b,c) =>
    a,
  {a,b,c,e}).a + ['a','b','A','B',a,b].map( (a,b,c) =>
    (a + b) == "AB" ? a + b : a
  ).filter( (a,b) =>
    (String(a) + String(b)).charCodeAt(2) == 97
  ).reduce( (a,b,c) =>
    a,
  {a,b,c,e})[(typeof +c)[Math.floor(Math.random() + 3)]];
};

console.log(amount(3, 5));
```

Только не спрашивайте как работает, сам запустался в процессе)))

Comment: почему тогда работает если Вы запутались в процессе ? :))

Comment: не запутали, выбирает из первого массива a из второго b и складывает https://jsfiddle.net/IvaMuxa/3j8L6uym/

Answer (score 4):

Берём код из вопроса, идём на http://www.jsfuck.com/ и получаем нечто из скобочек. Оно настолько длинное, что в ответ не лезет, но полная версия доступна на https://pastebin.com/31QahdKp

Если то же самое проделать с

```
const amount = (a, b) => a + b; console.log(amount(5, 3))
```

То получится (я поделил на строки по 64 символа)

```js
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][
(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!
![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[
]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+
(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!!
[]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+
[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(!
[]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![
]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+
!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[
+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!
+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]](([][
(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!
![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[
]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+
(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!!
[]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+
[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[
+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!
+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+((+[
])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!
+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+
[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+
[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+
[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[
!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]
+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[
]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[]
)[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[
][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])
[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]
]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[
]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+
!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[
])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])
[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+
!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[
]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!
+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+
[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[]
)[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])
[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+
!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[]
)[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[
+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]
+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+
(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+
[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][
[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!
+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(![]+[][(![]+[]
)[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])
[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[
]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+[[]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+
[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+
[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]
+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+
(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]
]+[])[+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+
[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[]
)[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]([[
]])+[]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]
+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[
])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!!
[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+
[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[
+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[
]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+
!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[
]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]
]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][
[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])
[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+
[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+
[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[
][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+
(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[
]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[]
)[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[!
[]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[
])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])
[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]
])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[
]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+
(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]
+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])
[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+
!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]
+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+
(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+
[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+[]])+(!![]+[][(![]+[]
)[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])
[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[
]]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[]
)[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[
+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[
+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+
[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([
][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])
[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+
!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[
])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[]
)[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]
+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]
+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!
+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[
+!+[]]]+([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+
[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(
![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!!
[]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]
+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[!+[]+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(!
[]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![
]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+
!+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+
!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+
[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(+(+!+[]+(!+[]+[])[!+
[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]])+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![
]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]
+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!
+[]]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(
[![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!
![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([
]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[
]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]
]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+
[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]
+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[
])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+
[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+
!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]
+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]
]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+
[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!
+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]
])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+
[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[
])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[
]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+
[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[]
)[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+
[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[]
)[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])
[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+
!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]
+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!
+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[
]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+[]])+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]
+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!
+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+
[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]
]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(
[![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!
![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+
[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+
[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]
]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+
(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(!
[]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![
]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+
[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]
]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+
!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+
[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[]
)[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!
![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[
]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]
]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]
]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+
(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]
+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]
])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+
!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+
[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])
[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[
+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(
[][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+
[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+
[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]
+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![
]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[
]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+
!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]
+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]
+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![
]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+
[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[]
[[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[
!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[
]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][
[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+
[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[]
)[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+
[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[
]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!!
[]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]
+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!
+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[
]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]
+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!
+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]
]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]
+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[
]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[
+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[
+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[
]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[]
[(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(
!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]
+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!
+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[]
)[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!
[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]
+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[
!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!
[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]
+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+
!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][
[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!
+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([]
[(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(
!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+
[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]
+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!
![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!
+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(
![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!!
[]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]
+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])
[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+
!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!
+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+
[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+
([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(
!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(
!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+
!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]
)[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]
+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([
![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!!
[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!!
[]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(
![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![
]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]]
(!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]
+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+
(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]
]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]
+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]
+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[
]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])
[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+
!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![
]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]
+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!
+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![
]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+
[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+
!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+
[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[
])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[
]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+
[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]
+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+
[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]
]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![
]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]
+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]
+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]
]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!
+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])
[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]
+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[
])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[
])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+
[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[]
)[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[
]+!+[]+[+[]]))+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[
]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]
+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[
]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+
[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![
]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]
+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[
]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[]
)[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])
[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+
(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(
!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[
!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!
[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]
+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]
+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+
(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+
(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]
+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]
])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![
]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(
[![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!
![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!
![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+
(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!!
[]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]
+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]
+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]
])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([!
[]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![
]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![
]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[
]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+
!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[]
)[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]
]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+
[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+
[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]
+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[
])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!
![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!
+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])
[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]
+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]
+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]
])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[[]][([][(![]+[])
[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[
+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!
+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])
[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+
!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]
+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[
])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[]
)[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]([[]])+[]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]
]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+
[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+[!+[]+!+[]
+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[
])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])
[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])
[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+
!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]])()
```

Comment: это запутанный способ вывести в консоль число 8. Лично я не вижу здесь нигде  переменных, а по условию вопроса это должно быть сложение переменных, с помощью этого можно сложить другие числа? кажется нет

Answer (score 2):

С оператором `?.` это я погорячился.

```js
function amount(a, b) {
  return (function helper({ll=2, ...a}) {
    return a.l1+ll-!a.b()+this.m()-((m?!3:1)?m:!(a.b.c||a.c))
  })(((ll,l1=~~ll+~ll+ll) => {
    return ({
      l1: (ll+l1+Boolean(ll||l1))/(!!(l1+ll)+((""+ll+l1).match((l1+ll)===(ll+ll))||(0||true))),
      b: function(){
        new Promise(r=>{window.m=()=>b}).then(()=>this.m=a);
      }
    })
  })(a));
}


console.log(amount(4,5))
```

Comment: Вы переопределяете `window.m`, от чего могут быть проблемы. Никогда не знаешь что будет в глобальной области видимости...)

Answer (score 2):

```js
function sum(...args){
  const o = Object.entries({
    map: "window",
    queue: "type",
    reducer: "proto",
    interval: "empty",
    reduce: "pop",
    push: "length",
  });
  let a = 0, b = 3, c = 1, d = o.shift().length / 2, k = new Object(null);
  if(args[0] == args[1]){
    const emptyString = (typeof k).split(/.+/)[0];
    k[o[a][a++]] = Array.from(emptyString);
    k[o[b-c][c-a]] = (a, b, c) => {if(!b){b = c - a;}while(a < c){a += b;}return {a, b, c};};
    k[o[--c][a]] = String(k[o[b][c]]).indexOf("\n");
  }else{
    k[o[c][a++]] = (a, b) => a - b;
    k[o[c+a+1][a-1]] = (a, b, c) => {while(a < b){a -= c;}return {a, b, c};};
    k[o[c][c--]] = number => k[o[0][+!0]] * number;
  }
  if(args[0] <= args[a] && args[1] <= args[c]){
    k[o[a][a]] = number => k[o[+!1][1]] * number;
    k[o[++c][--a]] = (a, b) => -b + a;
  }else{
    k[o[b-a][a]] = (typeof o).split(/.+/)[1];
    k[o[c][a--]] = String(k[o[b][c-0]]).indexOf("\n");
    k[o[a][c++]] = [];
  }
  while(args[o[b+c-a][c-a]]){
    k[o[a][c-c]][o[b+c-a][a]](args[o[1+b-c][c]]());
    k[o[c+b][c+a]] = k[o[c-c][a]][o[1+b-c][0]](k[o[+!0][a]], a);
  }
  return k[o[c][++a]](k[o[++b][c++]]);
}


// TEST
console.log("-= TEST =-");
[
  [1, 9],
  [11, 9],
  [1, 999999],
  [98765, 12345],
  [-123456, 330],
  [-11, -15],
  [-Math.random(), 1],
  [0, 0],
  [12345, 0],
  [999999999, 11],
  [0, -0.1],
].forEach(t => {
  const [a, b] = t;
  const c = a + b;
  const result = sum(a, b);
  console.log(`${a} + ${b} = ${result} ${result == c ? "YES" : "NO, "+c}`);
});
```

**Как оно работает:**

У нас есть пустой обьект, в который мы добавляем методы. Есть два условия, они добавляют методы в обьект в разной последовательности но, по факту, они одинаковые или делают то самое но другим способом.
Так же я сделал "словарь", который из обьекта превращается в массив 5х2, и потом используя переменные a, b, c, d и манипулируя ими получаем нужные свойства. Тут очень легко запутатся и сломать всё. Слова в словаре типа `map`, `window`, `proto`, `queue` на самом деле просто красивые слова, которые только сбивают с толку.

Все аргументы я проганяю через `Array.reduce` но я их не добавляю а вычитаю. А вконце умножаю на -1.

Так же я сделал защиту от деобфускации - если код обработать авто-форматированием, функция не перестанет работать, но будет возвращать не правильный результат.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю немного от себя. Есть пара японских обфускаторов [aaencode](http://utf-8.jp/public/aaencode.html) и [jjencode](http://utf-8.jp/public/jjencode.html).

Возьмем для примера

```
const amount = (a, b) => a + b; console.log(amount(5, 3))
```

на выходе получаем:

**aaencode:**

```js
ﾟωﾟﾉ = /｀ｍ´）ﾉ ~┻━┻   //*´∇｀*/ ['_']; o=(ﾟｰﾟ)  =_=3; c=(ﾟΘﾟ) =(ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟｰﾟ);
(ﾟДﾟ)=(ﾟΘﾟ)= (o^_^o)/ (o^_^o);(ﾟДﾟ)={ﾟΘﾟ: '_' ,ﾟωﾟﾉ : ((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3) +'_') [ﾟΘﾟ]
,ﾟｰﾟﾉ : (ﾟωﾟﾉ+ '_')[o^_^o -(ﾟΘﾟ)] ,ﾟДﾟﾉ:((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_')[ﾟｰﾟ] }; (ﾟДﾟ) [ﾟΘﾟ] =
((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3)+'_') [c^_^o];(ﾟДﾟ) ['c'] = ((ﾟДﾟ)+'_') [(ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟΘﾟ) ];(ﾟДﾟ
) ['o'] = ((ﾟДﾟ)+'_') [ﾟΘﾟ];(ﾟoﾟ)=(ﾟДﾟ) ['c']+(ﾟДﾟ) ['o']+ (ﾟωﾟﾉ +'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+
((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3)+'_') [ﾟｰﾟ] + ((ﾟДﾟ) +'_') [(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)] + ((ﾟｰﾟ==3) + '_') [ﾟΘﾟ]+(
(ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ) - (ﾟΘﾟ)]+(ﾟДﾟ) ['c']+((ﾟДﾟ)+'_') [(ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ)] + (ﾟДﾟ)
['o']+((ﾟｰﾟ==3) + '_') [ﾟΘﾟ];(ﾟДﾟ) ['_'] =(o^_^o) [ﾟoﾟ] [ﾟoﾟ];(ﾟεﾟ)=((ﾟｰﾟ==3
) +'_') [ﾟΘﾟ]+ (ﾟДﾟ).ﾟДﾟﾉ+((ﾟДﾟ)+'_') [(ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ)]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_') [o^_^o
-ﾟΘﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+ (ﾟωﾟﾉ +'_') [ﾟΘﾟ]; (ﾟｰﾟ)+=(ﾟΘﾟ); (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]='\\';
(ﾟДﾟ).ﾟΘﾟﾉ=(ﾟДﾟ+ﾟｰﾟ)[o^_^o -(ﾟΘﾟ)];(oﾟｰﾟo)=(ﾟωﾟﾉ + '_')[c^_^o]; (ﾟДﾟ) [ﾟoﾟ] =
'\"';(ﾟДﾟ) ['_']((ﾟДﾟ) ['_'] (ﾟεﾟ+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ]+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (o^_^o
)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o)) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ) + (
(ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ ((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) + (o^_^o)) +
(o^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o)) + (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟｰﾟ) + (
c^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ) + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (
(ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)
[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o)) + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) +
(ﾟΘﾟ))+ ((o^_^o) + (o^_^o)) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+
(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+ (c^_^o) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] +((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o)) + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)) +
(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+ (c^_^o) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (c^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]
+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+
(c^_^o) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟΘﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) - (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) +
(ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+ (c^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] +((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+((ﾟｰﾟ)
+ (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o)) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)
+ (c^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + (ﾟｰﾟ) + (c^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)
[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (o^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ) + (c^_^o) + (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+
(ﾟｰﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) - (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o)) + (o^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+
(ﾟｰﾟ)+(c^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (o^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) +(ﾟΘﾟ
))+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ ((o^_^o) + (o^_^o))+
(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ (o^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ
))+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ
)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ
)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ ((ﾟｰﾟ)
+(o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟΘﾟ
))+(c^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+
((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]
+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟΘﾟ))+
((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(
(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+ (c^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)) + (ﾟДﾟ)
[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+ (c^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] + ((o^_^o) +
(o^_^o))+ (o^_^o)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ)
)+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ])(ﾟΘﾟ)) ('_');
```

**jjencode:**

```js
$=~[];$={___:++$,$$$$:(![]+"")[$],__$:++$,$_$_:(![]+"")[$],_$_:++$,$_$$:({}
+"")[$],$$_$:($[$]+"")[$],_$$:++$,$$$_:(!""+"")[$],$__:++$,$_$:++$,$$__:({}
+"")[$],$$_:++$,$$$:++$,$___:++$,$__$:++$};$.$_=($.$_=$+"")[$.$_$]+($._$=$.
$_[$.__$])+($.$$=($.$+"")[$.__$])+((!$)+"")[$._$$]+($.__=$.$_[$.$$_])+($.$=
(!""+"")[$.__$])+($._=(!""+"")[$._$_])+$.$_[$.$_$]+$.__+$._$+$.$;$.$$=$.$+(
!""+"")[$._$$]+$.__+$._+$.$+$.$$;$.$=($.___)[$.$_][$.$_];$.$($.$($.$$+"\""+
$.$$__+$._$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+$.__+"\\"+$.$__+$
.___+$.$_$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$_$+$._$+$._+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_+$.__+"\\"
+$.$__+$.___+"=\\"+$.$__+$.___+"("+$.$_$_+",\\"+$.$__+$.___+$.$_$$+")\\"+$.
$__+$.___+"=>\\"+$.$__+$.___+$.$_$_+"\\"+$.$__+$.___+"+\\"+$.$__+$.___+$.$_$$
+";\\"+$.$__+$.___+$.$$__+$._$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$
+$._$+(![]+"")[$._$_]+$.$$$_+"."+(![]+"")[$._$_]+$._$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$__+$.$$$
+"("+$.$_$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$_$+$._$+$._+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_+$.__+"("+
$.$_$+",\\"+$.$__+$.___+$._$$+"))"+"\"")())();
```

Comment: Опять же очень круто но где указывать переменные?

Comment: Просто пройтись по коду онлайн-обфускатором - любой ребенок сможет. Так не интересно, для того и сделали конкурс... Иначе можно просто пробежатся обфускатором 3-6 раз и готово¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sum(a, b){
  var normalize = function(chunk, seed = 10){
    var status = chunk > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    if(chunk < 0){
      chunk = (status * chunk) % seed;
    }else{
      chunk = chunk % seed;
    }
    return status * chunk;
  };
  var buffers = {
    primary: [],
    secondary: [],
    temp: [],
  };
  do{
    do{
      buffers.secondary.push(normalize(a));
      a = a >= 0 ? Math.floor(a / 10) : Math.ceil(a / 10);
    }while(Math.abs(a) >= 1)
      
    do{
      buffers.temp.push(normalize(b));
      b = b >= 0 ? Math.floor(b / 10) : Math.ceil(b / 10);
    }while(Math.abs(b) >= 1)
  }while(Math.abs(a) >= 1 || Math.abs(b) >= 1)

  while(buffers.secondary.length < buffers.temp.length){
    while(buffers.secondary.length) buffers.primary.push(buffers.secondary.shift());
    while(buffers.temp.length) buffers.secondary.push(buffers.temp.shift());
    while(buffers.primary.length) buffers.temp.push(buffers.primary.shift());
  }
  
  var chunkIndex = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<buffers.secondary.length; i++){
    var hash = 0;
    [buffers.temp[i], [-a, buffers.secondary], chunkIndex, buffers.secondary[i], [buffers.temp, -b], 0]
      .forEach(function(chunk, index, array){
        if(!Number(chunk)){
          return index;
        }
        hash += chunk;
        chunkIndex -= chunkIndex;
      });
    if(hash + 1 > 10){
      chunkIndex = 1;
      hash = normalize(hash, 10);
    }
    buffers.primary[i] = hash;
  }
  if(chunkIndex){
    buffers.primary.push(1);
    chunkIndex--;
  }
  while(buffers.primary.length){
    chunkIndex = chunkIndex * 10 + buffers.primary.pop();
  }
  return buffers, chunkIndex;
}


// TEST
console.log("-= TEST =-");
[
  [1, 9],
  [11, 9],
  [1, 999999],
  [98765, 12345],
  [-123456, 330],
  [-11, -15],
  [-Math.random(), 1],
  [0, 0],
  [12345, 0],
  [999999999, 11],
  [0, -0.1],
].forEach(t => {
  const [a, b] = t;
  const c = a + b;
  const result = sum(a, b);
  console.log(`${a} + ${b} = ${result} ${result == c ? "YES" : "NO, "+c}`);
});
```

---

Если не очень понятно как оно работает - ниже представлен вариант попроще - в нем только сложный алгоритм, без обфускации.

```js
function sum(a, b){
  // Превращаем число в массив разрядов, развернутый задом-наперед
  // 123 => 3, 2, 1
  // 12.45 => 2.45, 1
  var a_array = [];
  do{
    a_array.push(a % 10);
    a = a >= 0 ? Math.floor(a / 10) : Math.ceil(a / 10);
  }while(Math.abs(a) >= 1)
  var b_array = [];
  do{
    b_array.push(b % 10);
    b = b >= 0 ? Math.floor(b / 10) : Math.ceil(b / 10);
  }while(Math.abs(b) >= 1)

  // Если второе число больше первого - меняем их местами
  if(a_array.length < b_array.length){
    var temp = a_array;
    a_array = b_array;
    b_array = temp;
  }
  
  var result_array = [];
  var memory = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<a_array.length; i++){
    // первое число, второе и "запомненное" число, если было
    // Сюда же можно запихнуть любые числа, которые в сумме будут давать ноль
    // И любую фигню, которая будет давать NaN
    var additions = [b_array[i], memory, a_array[i]];
    var tempSum = 0;
    additions.filter(Number).forEach(function(number){
      tempSum += number;
    });
    memory = 0;
    if(tempSum > 9){
      memory = 1;
      tempSum = tempSum % 10;
    }
    result_array[i] = tempSum;
  }
  if(memory){
    result_array.push(1);
  }

  var result = 0;
  while(result_array.length){
    result *= 10;
    result += result_array.pop();
  }
  return result;
}


// TEST
console.log("-= TEST =-");
[
  [1, 9],
  [11, 9],
  [1, 999999],
  [98765, 12345],
  [-123456, 330],
  [-11, -15],
  [-Math.random(), 1],
  [0, 0],
  [12345, 0],
  [999999999, 11],
  [0, -0.1],
].forEach(t => {
  const [a, b] = t;
  const c = a + b;
  const result = sum(a, b);
  console.log(`${a} + ${b} = ${result} ${result == c ? "YES" : "NO, "+c}`);
});
```

Да-да, это школьная арифметика, добавление в столбик. Потом я немного запутал код, дал переменным логические названия, которые совсем не связаны с реальным предназначением, а некоторые переменные я использовал по пару раз для разных целей (например, `chunkIndex` или `buffers.primary`)